# How to install modules to IronPython in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I need to use Python code in the C# application. So I decide to install IronPython NuGet to my project in VisualStudio. When I try to run the script, I always have errors with the Python Modules (like numpy, json...).

I tried solutions like include path to the folder with modules.

```
# first try
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("some.py");
test.Test();

# error 1
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named numpy'

# the tried this
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(...pathToModules);
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
dynamic logging = engine.ImportModule("numpy");

#error 2
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token 'append''
```

I'm using Anaconda with Spyder, python version 3.5. The problem isn't about python version.

Can you help me please to solve it? It's possible to install some modules to the IronPython in VisualStudio environment?